# Probability and counting problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose that 40 cats and 40 dogs walk in random order.
Show that the probability to never have two cats and two dogs successively is of the order of the inverse of Avogadro's number.

First i said that their is 40 out of 80 combinaisons possible but i can't conclude

Answer (score 0):

There are only two relevant sequences:  DCDCDC... and CDCDCD... out of the total of ${80 \choose 40}$ possible sequences.

Comment: Ooopsss... yes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The probability a cat goes first is 40/80= 1/2.  Then there are 40 dogs and 39 cats left.  The probability the next is a dog is  40/79.  In that case there are 39 dogs and 39 cats so the probability the next is a cat is 39/78.  In that case there are 39 dogs and 38 cats so the probabily the next is a dog is 39/77.  Continuing that way we get to (2/4)(2/3)(1/2)(1/1).  The probability this happens- a cat goes first and then dogs and cats alternate is the product of all those, $\frac{(40!)^2}{80!}$.

The probability a dog goes first is also 40/80 and then exactly the same analysis applies- The probability a dog goes first and then they alternate is also $\frac{(40!)^2}{80!}$.

Since one OR the other of those happens (rather than "and") those add rather than multiply.  The probability the animals alternate is $\frac{2(40!)^2}{80!}$.

Answer (score -2):

I am unsure that I could answer this question more completely, but since you're a new member, I'd suggest that we consider the following:

- Let's call the set of all the cats C. The total number of cats is then |C| = 40.
- Let's call the set of all the dogs D. The total number of dogs is then |D| = 40.

Given the above, there's a total probability given by Bayes' Theorem/Rule:
P(A|B) = (P(B|A)*P(A))/P(B)

I think that should be sufficient to answer your question, but given that we have no sets A or B defined, despite defining C and D previously:
P(C|D) = (P(D|C)*P(C))/P(D))
And since we know (by definition) that P(B) is non-zero, then we can solve using something like Mathematica or Wolfram Alpha:
P((C|D)) = P(P(D union C)) * P(C))/P(D).

Let me know if that's sufficient as an answer, I am not very good at MathJax.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Bayes' Theorem.